# why i am not able to transfer images from Redmi 1s to my laptop via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, windows, bluetooth-pairing, redmi-1s

Well, I was trying to transfer images from my REDMI 1S device to my laptop but don't know why my every attempt is unsuccessful whether I am trying to send images in bulk or one at a time?Can anyone help me to sort this out?
There is no issue with pairing up my device..!!
Just images are not sent and the message appears the attempt to the sent image is unsuccessful.

Comment: Settings> apps> from 3 dot menu > show system apps > Bluetooth > storage > clear data and cache and try after paying again. On the PC also depending on OS similar action may be required

Comment: @beeshyams no bluetooth  is present in system apps so what to do now?

Comment: @beeshyams may be system os settings have changed  ,bluetooth is there but not in system settings.

Comment: @beeshyams but there is no cache for Bluetooth anywhere its showing 0.00B in app

Comment: Can't say then but on your laptop try clearing Bluetooth data. May help IDK

Comment: What windows version are you using? Dies it have custom Bluetooth transfer software? Try using default **fsquirt**, to transfer the files. That was the exact problem I had when I upgraded to Windows 10